# Tenant gets too big, move it into different container?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Let's assume I've started a SaaS platform with Azure Cosmos DB as my backend. I set up a container and used the tenant ID (a GUID) as the partition key. Things work well until we get two large clients. The overall system and the two large clients in particular would benefit a lot if we could move the two large clients into a different container and use more fine-grained partition keys for them. This is a bit a burden of us at the application-level, but it's doable.

How to move a whole "partition key" into a different container with a more fine-grained partition key? Is this something we can do "on-the-fly"? Do we need to take that tenant offline and use some sort of tool to migrate all the data? Is there a best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there's no built-in way of doing that, but there is as path forward, its called [change feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed). Basically you can use the change feed to migrate all the data from the beginning of the database to the last change. You would need to implement a filter to only filter on changes on that tenant partition key and you would also need to implement a way to distribute that tenants data across several partitions. There are some limitations to change feed, though.

Some other [ways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/cosmosdb-migrationchoices).

Comment: Okay, thanks. I hoped that there is some kind of tooling support to do this, but it looks like we've got to manually copy them over and then delete them at the source...unfortunate.